# Tk button wait for variable pausing program

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a simple GUI in Jupyter Notebook that holds a dropdown menu that allows a linear scale to be selected then for a button to be pressed when the selection is made. The button should close the GUI and the variable, 'Lin_scale,' should hold the information selected in the dropdown box.

Right now, I can select from the dropdown menu, but when I click the button, nothing seems to happen. The button can be visibly seen being clicked and after clicking, I can select another option from the dropdown menu. So the program is not frozen, but rather the logic to catch when the button is pressed is not working.

```
root2 = tk.Tk()
root2.title('Linear Scale')
root2.config(width= 300, height= 200)


#Create Frame

frame = tk.Frame(root2, width= 300, height= 200, bg= 'grey')
frame.grid(row= 0, column= 0, padx= 10, pady= 5)


#Dropdown
combo = ttk.Combobox(
    frame,
    #state= 'readonly',
    values= ['Low', 'Medium', 'High']
    )

combo.grid(column=1, row=0)

var = tk.IntVar()

button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Set scale", command= lambda: var.set(1))
button.grid(column= 2, row= 0)
button.wait_variable()

Lin_scale = combo.get()

root2.destroy()
```

Comment: Why are you calling `root2.destroy()` right before calling `root2.mainloop()`?

Comment: Also, you're missing a closing single quote in your list of dropdown values - I assume that's just a transcription error!

Comment: Figured out the mainloop() was also causing issues, so I got rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

You are neglecting to tell tkinter which variable to wait on. You should pass `var` to `wait_variable`.

```
button.wait_variable(var)
```

Also, based on the variable name I'm guessing you might also have the problem that you're creating more than one instance of `Tk` but not configuring the variable to belong to the second instance. If that's the case, you need to specify `master` when creating the variable.

```
var = tk.IntVar(master=root2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to use `wait_variable()`. Just destroy the window if something is selected and the <kbd>Set scale</kbd> button is clicked. Then you can get the selected value from the tkinter variable linked with the combobox.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def confirm():
    if var.get():
        # something selected, close root window
        root2.destroy()

root2 = tk.Tk()
root2.title('Linear Scale')
root2.config(width=300, height=200)

frame = tk.Frame(root2, bg='grey')
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)

var = tk.StringVar(master=root2)
combo = ttk.Combobox(
    frame,
    textvariable=var,
    state='readonly',
    values=['Low', 'Medium', 'High']
)
combo.grid(column=1, row=0)

button = ttk.Button(
    frame,
    text="Set scale",
    command=confirm
)
button.grid(column=2, row=0)

root2.mainloop()

Lin_scale = var.get()
print(f"{Lin_scale=}")
```

Comment: This approach is better suited for `tkinter` as it's [event driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). +1